# How to plot error bars in a Seaborn FacetGrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I need to plot error bars for this facetgrid in a pandas dataframe on a Seaborn FacetGrid

This is the code I am using

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df1_melted,col='AA', col_wrap=4)
g = g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot,"VFAs","mgCOD/L",hue='VFAs',errorbar=None,palette = sns.color_palette("bright"))
for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim((0, 650))
    plt.legend().remove
```